# bootstrap cannot toggle when using d-none d-lg-block

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I created a navbar that will appear only on large screens

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="d-none d-lg-block">
...
</nav>
```

I also created a toggler that will show/hide the navbar on click

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#sidebar').toggle();"><i class="fa fa-bars custom-icon"></i></a>
```

The problem is that when I click the icon the navbar does not hide and `display: none;` does not have any effect when using `d-none d-lg-block`

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Amine Messaoudi  please add proper code snippet for better understanding.

Comment: `toggle` adds `display:none` inline...right. It does nothing to disable the `d-none` class. Try `toggleClass("d-none")` instead.

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: Then you need to *minimally* **demo** the issue in a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that if display is none and we add `d-lg-block` then the navbar it appears again, which was the main problem as i was not able to hide the nav while that class was still present. So I created a function that will first remove it before hiding

```
$("#toggler").click(function()
{
    if($("#sidebar").css('display') === 'none')
    {
        $("#sidebar").addClass("d-none");
        $("#sidebar").addClass("d-lg-block");
        $("#sidebar").toggle();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#sidebar").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#sidebar").removeClass("d-lg-block");
        $("#sidebar").toggle();
    }  
});
```

I hope this will be useful to anyone encountering the same thing

Comment: this is the wrong way dude please refer the BS4 Navbar examples on BS4 official website or from W3School.

Answer (score 0):

`d-none` sets the display as `display:none!important` meaning it can only be overwritten by other css that is also `!important`.

You could try this, although it's not very pretty:

```js
function toggle($elmnt) {
  if($elmnt.css('display') === 'none') {
    $elmnt.css({'cssText': 'display: block!important;'});
  } else {
    $elmnt.css({'cssText': 'display: none!important;'});
  }  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="sidebar" class="d-none d-lg-block">
navbar here
</nav>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle($('#sidebar'));"><i class="fa fa-bars custom-icon"></i>toggle navbar</a>
```

Comment: he is working with BS4 so this custom code is just waste of time.

Comment: His question was how he could toggle the entire navbar to show or hide it, which the answer provides.

Comment: ya but using BS4 classes navbar-expand-xl, navbar-expand-lg, navbar-expand-md, navbar-expand-sm. he can make toggle respectively for the width 1199px, 991px, 767px, 575px. so just guide him to use the BS4 classes in proper way.

Comment: The problem was with `d-lg-block` as it overrides display none. The key was to remove it before calling `$('#sidebar").toggle()`

Comment: @KuldipKoradia These classes do not hide the **entire** navbar. Which is what he was trying to do.

Comment: ya he have to use proper classes so tell you to guide him in a right way nothing else and you are also wrong by providing this type of solution.

Comment: @KuldipKoradia then please provide an answer using the default BS4 classes that allows him to hide the **ENTIRE** navbar. Not just a part of it.

Comment: @KuldipKoradia your answer does not hide the ---> **ENTIRE** <---- navbar. Only a part of it. Come on man I have highlighted this 3 times already.

Answer (score -1):

can you please follow the exact structure to make Navbar using BS4.

pure BS4 Navbar is like below snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

I hope this code is help to solve your problem.

Thank you...